# Xcode save code folding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, code-formatting, code-folding

I know it's not directly related to programming, but what better place then stackoverflow right?

So code folding is an awesome feature which I love, but does anyone know if there is a way to get Xcode to remember where you have certain sections collapsed whenever you open a file?

BTW, I'm coding ruby on rails using git version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code folding for a source file is saved in the user file of the project.  So if you're just editing a naked Ruby source file, there's no place to store the information.  You might just make a dummy Empty Project and add the Ruby files to it just to persist the folding state, scroll position, etc. even if you don't use the project for building or version control.

Comment: Scroll position is maintained for me, but not code folding. Any idea why?